# Нужно отменить по умолчанию подсветку в меню навигации при нажатии на ссылки

Tags: css

При создании меню навигации в Header.по умолчанию при нажатии на ссылки, цвет ссылки становится красным. Как можно убрать цвет при нажатии на ссылки.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, Ваш код

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Без Вашего кода, как говорится, ничего не понятно, но очень интересно... По умолчанию:

1. ссылки подчёркнуты
2. не посещённые ссылки синего цвета
3. посещенные ссылки фиолетового цвета
4. при наведении курсора на ссылку первый превращается в руку
5. активные ссылки красного цвета.

Если в Вашем вопросе речь идёт про :active, т.е. про момент активации ссылки пользователем (момент нажатия на ссылку), т.е. если Вы не хотите, чтобы в момент нажатия на синюю ссылку она НЕ горела красным, то можно поступить следующим образом: задайте цвет для `a:link` (не посещенная ссылка) и для `a:visited` (посещенная ссылка) (цвета могут быть одинаковые или разные). Эти два псевдокласса перекроют :active и тогда ссылка, в момент нажатия на нее, не будет гореть красным.

```css
a {
font-size: 30px;
}
a:link {
color: blue;
}
a:visited {
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/">Ссылка</a>
```

```css
a {
  font-size: 30px;
}

a:link {
  color: blue;
}

a:visited {
  color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/">Ссылка</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Все выполнено.... получается у псевдокласса по умолчанию свои стили.

Comment: @v333, Да, по умолчанию у псевдоклассов есть свои стили.  По умолчанию псевдокласс `:active` задает ссылке красный цвет в момент активации (т.е. когда пользователь нажимает на ссылку). Для того, чтобы отключить этот стиль по умолчанию для `:active`, Вы можете его либо перекрыть, задав одинаковый или разный цвет для `:link` (не посещенная ссылка) и для `:visited` (посещенная ссылка). Либо можете задать `:link` и `:active` одиноковый цвет ссылки. Любой из этих двух методов уберет красное свечение у `:active`